# will_paginate with resources route collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, will-paginate

Can't quite figure out what's going on here. So in my routes I have

```
sso.namespace(:admin) do |admin|
  admin.resources :locations, :collection => {:search => :post}
```

Generating the pagination just fine on the view.  Here's my view code:

```
<%= will_paginate @search_locations, :class => "loc_pagination", :params => {:controller => 'sso/admin/locations', :action => 'search'}, :style => "text-align: center;" if @search_locations %>
```

Problem is that when I click on the links, it fires a GET request and sticks search in the params.  Here is the parameters in the server log.

```
Parameters: {"action"=>"show", "id"=>"search", "page"=>"2", "controller"=>"sso/admin/locations"}
```

The generated html code looks sound, but I can't figure out what it's doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've configured the search action to only respond to `post` requests. When you attempt to visit the second page of the search results (via a get request) the show route picks up the response. Try changing the `:collection => { :search => :any }` and append the search term to the params passed to will_paginate.

Comment: didn't know I could do :any. It's always simple with rails.

Comment: I believe you could also be a bit more explicit and use `[ :get, :post ]` to avoid any additional confusion.